# Questions about fitting a normal+lognormal mixture model

Tags: jags, mixture-model, winbugs14

I am now working on using a mixture model including two components: normal and lognormal to fit a vector.
I tried using JAGS, here is the code:

```
model {
   for(i in 1:N) {
     y[i] <- latent[i,index[i]+1]
     index[i] ~dbern(pi)
     latent[i,1]~ dlnorm(mu1,tau1)
     latent[i,2]~ dnorm(mu2,tau2)}
     pi ~ dbeta(0.5,0.5)
     mu1 ~ dnorm(0.4,0.000001)
     tau1~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
     mu2 ~ dnorm(4,0.000001)
     tau2~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
}
```

However, it does not work with an error message "y[1] is a logical node and cannot be observed".
I also tried

```
y[i] <- pi*z1+(1-pi)*z2

z1 ~ dnorm(mu1,tau1)

z2 ~ dlnorm(mu2,tau2)
```

...

But it gave the same error message. It seems I have to assign a distribution to y[i]. Could anyone help to overcome this problem? or other approaches for solving such a mixture model would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to mix these two models you could do something like this:

```
model {
   for(i in 1:N) {
     index[i] ~dbern(pi)
     latent[i]~ (dlnorm(mu1,tau1)*(1-index[i]))+(dnorm(mu2,tau2)*index[i]) 
}
     pi ~ dbeta(0.5,0.5)
     mu1 ~ dnorm(0.4,0.000001)
     tau1~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
     mu2 ~ dnorm(4,0.000001)
     tau2~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
}
```

That way, in each step of the model it either chooses to use the lognormal or the normal model.  If you track `index` it will tell you which distribution is chosen at each step in the MCMC chain (index = 1 = normal, index = 0 = lognormal).  Furthermore, you can take the sum of index and divide by the number of steps in your MCMC chain to get the proportion of times that 1 was chosen (normal).

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply! I tried your code but the error message is "Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 4 near "(" "

Comment: Ah. Change `latent[i]~ (dlnorm(mu1,tau1)*(1-index[i]))+(dnorm(mu2,tau2)*index[i]) ` to `y[i]~ (dlnorm(mu1,tau1)*(1-index[i]))+(dnorm(mu2,tau2)*index[i])` and see if that works. If it does I will edit the answer.